# Separating the google recaptcha example into a form and response page

Tags: php, recaptcha

To do recaptcha I am following this example:

https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php

What I am having trouble with is what piece of this code do I have on the form itself and what part do I have on the page that handles the PHP (in my case the form to e-mail page). It looks like they have it all on one page but this form is on a modal in the footer (so it is on every page) so the less PHP that has to be ran every page load the better... so I am hoping I can move some to the form to e-mail script side of things.

Like would I just have my site key on the form page and then for the line

```
$siteKey = '';
```

Would I just use something like:

```
$siteKey = $_Post["siteKey"];
```

and then have all of the code in the example on the form to email script?

Or... would I keep all this on this on the form side and it would only successfully post if the siteKey corresponds with the secret key?

Comment: Thier must an config file where you will put all your secret key . site key you are not supposed to post or show to someone. Else put your keys in some file and include in this page

Comment: You put your secret key in the php so it is only seen on server side. I just don't know how I can divide up what goes in front and what goes in back.